# Rails: Devise + CanCan cannot see any views

Tags: ruby-on-rails, authentication, view, controller, devise

Im using Devise/Cancan in my rails app.

I haven't overridden the default devise controller. I have generated the default devise views. Now Id like to link to all the default devise views from an admin panel.

So I have the following admin_panel_view

```
<h1>Administrator Dash Board</h1>
    <ul>

    <li><%=link_to "Sign Up user",  user_password_path %></li>
    <li><%=link_to "Sign Up user",  new_user_password_path %></li>
    <li><%=link_to "Sign Up user",  edit_user_password_path %></li>
    <li><%=link_to "Sign Up user",  cancel_user_registration_path %></li>
    <li><%=link_to "Sign Up user",  user_registration_path %></li>
    <li><%=link_to "Sign Up user",  edit_user_registration_path %></li>     
    <li><%=link_to "Sign Up user",  users_path %></li>

</ul>
```

When I click on any of these links they donot work.

Here is my routes file:

```
resources :businesses
resources :addresses
resources :images
devise_for :users
resources :users , :only => [:show, :index]

authenticated :user do
  root :to => "listings#index"
end

root :to => "listings#index"

resources :listings


resources :admin_dash_board, :only => :index
```

Inside my app I have these views set up through Devise view generator:

```
Views/devise/confirmations/*
Views/devise/mailer/*
Views/devise/passwords/*
Views/devise/registrations/*
Views/devise/sessions/*
Views/devise/shared/*
Views/devise/unlocks/*
```

Is there anything Im missing? How can I get them to work?Thanks in  advance

Comment: What does “do not work“ mean? What kind of error are you getting?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, until you give more information I can't be sure, but in your routes, you need to have a `:path_prefix` for the devise_for like so: `devise_for :users, :path_prefix => 'd'`

That will make sure that you don't have duplicate routes between devise and the `resources :users` that you have. Here's the page on the devise wiki that talks about it: https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To:-Manage-users-through-a-CRUD-interface

Comment: Sorry about the lack of information. Still trying to learn.

Basically I followed the tutorials on railscasts and got devise and cancan to work. I want to use rolify as well, Ive downloaded that gem but haven't added any roles besides admins as yet. All my users are admins. Now I want to add more roles. I would like to do user maintenance from my admin page. However, I haven't created a User Controller. im just using the one that came with devise. I would like to use my own user controller and then get the links working. Could you please point me to some tutorials or how to get started. Thanks

Comment: That link I provided will help get you started. Check out the other pages on the devise wiki. They've got several dedicated to exactly what you're trying to accomplish.